# Select values of one array based on a boolean expression applied to another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Starting with the following array

```
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,   0.,  nan,  nan])
```

which is generated like so:

```
import numpy as np
row = np.array([ np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,   1.,  np.nan,  np.nan,   0.,  np.nan,  np.nan])
```

I'd like to get the indices of the sorted array and then exclude the `nans`. In this case, I'd like to get `[6,3]`.

I've come up with the following way to do this:

```
vals = np.sort(row)
inds = np.argsort(row)

def select_index_by_value(indices, values):
    selected_indices = []
    for i in range(len(indices)):
        if not np.isnan(values[i]):
            selected_indices.append(indices[i])
    return selected_indices

selected_inds = select_index_by_value(inds, vals)
```

Now `selected_inds` is `[6,3]`. However, this seems like quite a few lines of code to achieve something simple. Is there perhaps a shorter way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
row.argsort()[~np.isnan(np.sort(row))]
# array([6, 3])
```

Comment: Both solutions work, but I find the use of boolean indexing more elegant than Numpy's `where`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this -

```
# Store non-NaN indices
idx = np.where(~np.isnan(row))[0]

# Select non-NaN elements, perform argsort and use those argsort       
# indices to re-order non-NaN indices as final output
out = idx[row[idx].argsort()]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another faster solution (for OP data).

Psidom's Solution

```
%timeit row.argsort()[~np.isnan(np.sort(row))]

The slowest run took 31.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.16 µs per loop
```

Divakar's Solution

```
%timeit idx = np.where(~np.isnan(row))[0]; idx[row[idx].argsort()]

The slowest run took 35.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.73 µs per loop
```

Based on Divakar's Solution

```
%timeit np.where(~np.isnan(row))[0][::-1]

The slowest run took 9.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.86 µs per loop
```

I think this works because `np.where(~np.isnan(row))` retains order.